# Shards /replicas not being allocated on a new node on another machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and have been playing around with its features.

1. I have a single node(master=true,data=true) running on a single machine. I create an index with 3 shards and 1 replica for each shard. The health goes yellow as the replica shards cannot be allocated on the same node.
2. So I create another node(master=false,data=true) on the SAME machine, and the health goes green as the replica shards are now allocated on this new node.

Now here's the problem :

If I create the second node on ANOTHER machine on the LAN instead of the same machine, the node joins the cluster(as seen from the chrome sense plugin) but the replica shards are not being allocated to this node.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check elasticsearch logs on both nodes?

Comment: Are you sure that the second node is really in the same cluster as the first node? What happens when you try to manually move one of the shards onto the second node with the cluster reroute api? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html

Answer (score 0):

Add your master node host to `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` value list in config/elasticsearch.yml.
See http://www.elasticsearch.com/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#unicast